# Compare static column with calculated column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a pivot in Power Bi, which shows me how the sum of a value in a table compares with a static "expected" value in another table. So i need to calculate the sum of the datalog table, grouped by name and the month, which is fine, but then i need to compare that result to a static table, also by name, for each month. This would be a 2 second job in Excel, so I'm sure I'm missing something relatively straightforward in DAX/Power BI?

Thanks

Budget Table

<kbd>Tom</kbd><kbd>Bills</kbd>            <kbd>500</kbd>
<kbd>Tom</kbd><kbd>Shopping</kbd>   <kbd>500</kbd>
<kbd>Tom</kbd><kbd>Other</kbd>          <kbd>500</kbd>
<kbd>Joe</kbd><kbd>Bills</kbd>            <kbd>500</kbd>
<kbd>Joe</kbd><kbd>Shopping</kbd>   <kbd>500</kbd>
<kbd>Joe</kbd><kbd>Other</kbd>          <kbd>500</kbd>

Log Table

<kbd>01/01/2001</kbd><kbd>Tom</kbd><kbd>Bills</kbd>            <kbd>50</kbd>
<kbd>01/02/2001</kbd><kbd>Joe</kbd><kbd>Shopping</kbd>   <kbd>10</kbd>
<kbd>01/02/2001</kbd><kbd>Joe</kbd><kbd>Bills</kbd>          <kbd>35</kbd>
<kbd>01/07/2001</kbd><kbd>Tom</kbd><kbd>Bills</kbd>          <kbd>35</kbd>
<kbd>02/01/2001</kbd><kbd>Tom</kbd><kbd>Bills</kbd>            <kbd>50</kbd>
<kbd>02/02/2001</kbd><kbd>Joe</kbd><kbd>Shopping</kbd>   <kbd>20</kbd>
<kbd>02/02/2001</kbd><kbd>Joe</kbd><kbd>Bills</kbd>          <kbd>45</kbd>
<kbd>02/07/2001</kbd><kbd>Tom</kbd><kbd>Bills</kbd>          <kbd>35</kbd>

Wanted Result

<kbd>Name</kbd><kbd>Category</kbd><kbd>Jan</kbd><kbd>Feb</kbd>
<kbd>Tom</kbd><kbd>Bills</kbd>            <kbd>415</kbd><kbd>415</kbd>
<kbd>Tom</kbd><kbd>Shopping</kbd>   <kbd>500</kbd><kbd>500</kbd>
<kbd>Tom</kbd><kbd>Other</kbd>          <kbd>500</kbd><kbd>500</kbd>
<kbd>Joe</kbd><kbd>Bills</kbd>            <kbd>465</kbd><kbd>455</kbd>
<kbd>Joe</kbd><kbd>Shopping</kbd>   <kbd>490</kbd><kbd>480</kbd>
<kbd>Joe</kbd><kbd>Other</kbd>          <kbd>500</kbd><kbd>500</kbd>

Comment: John, what are the relations between these tables? Ideally, please post an image of your data model.

Comment: Thanks for your comment RADO, but the relationships should be very obvious. Name, Category, Budget and Log are the tables where the Name and Category are linked

Comment: The relations are not obvious at all. Are both Budget and Log tables designed as fact tables? If so, where is date key in Budget table, and what is its granularity? Are Name and Category designed as shared dimensions? Do you have a calendar/date dimension in you model?

Comment: I'm afraid you are looking for a complicated problem and an overdesigned data model where this is actually very simple. I will post the solution I came up with shortly. I would recommend you consider how little value there is in having a date key in a table of static data!!! :D :D

Answer (score 0):

General rule is if you are trying to have date (or month in your example) in the column **in your data model** in the PowerBI, you are doing something wrong.

For example, instead there is a matrix visual which allows placing date on the X axis to get similar effect in a "canonical" way.

If you describe the end result you are trying to achieve, we may be able to help better.

Otherwise, here is a primitive example of what you asked (but don't do this)

---

Calculated columns (both tables):

```
key = [name]&[category]
```

Add relationship between `key` columns

Calculated columns in the budget table:

```
jan = CALCULATE(SUM(budget[budget])-SUM('log'[amount]),MONTH('log'[date])=1)

feb = CALCULATE(SUM(budget[budget])-SUM('log'[amount]),MONTH('log'[date])=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually discovered a much simpler method late last night. Will post when i get out of work! Basic jist is that I just create a measure = sum of log.value and another measure = sum of budget.value and a third measure simply calculating the difference. After that i just drag the third measure into a pivot visualization with the name and category and i'm done.